# Prove that $Fonk(I,G)$ is a group under $*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $I$ be any set and $G$ be a group. Let $Fonk(I,G)$ be set of functions from $I$ to $G.$ Let $e$ be identity element of $G$. If $f,g\in Fonk(I,G)$ then, for $i\in I$
>
> $$(f*g)(i)=f(i)*g(i).$$
>
> Prove that $Fonk(I,G)$ is a group under $*$.

My Proof-trying. Let $f,g,h\in Fonk(I,G).$ Then

$G1.$ $((f*g)(i))*h(i)=f(i)*g(i)*h(i)$ and similarly $f(i)*((g(i)*h(i))=f(i)*g(i)*h(i).$

$G2$. $(f*e)(i)=f(i)*e(i)=f(i)$ because $f(i)\in G$ and $e$ is identity element of $G$ and similarly $(e*f)(i)=e(i)*f(i)=f(i).$

$G3.$ Let $f^{-1}$ be inverse element of $f$ in $G$. Then $(f*f^{-1})(i)=f(i)*f^{-1}(i)=e$ because $f(i),f^{-1}(i)\in G$ and $f^{-1}$ is inverse element of $f$.

**Can you check my answer?** Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requires the definition of the inverse of such a function $f$:

$g(i) = f(i)^{-1}$ for all $i\in I$.

Then $g$ is the inverse of $f$, written $g=f^{-1}$ as its unique.